# js regexp floating number with leading zero

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to make an input mask that meets the following requirements:

1. 1255454 - ok
2. 1.54546 - ok
3. 1,0056 - ok
4. 0.6565 - ok
5. 0,0056 - ok
6. 056565 - not ok
7. ds5asd - not ok
8. .0565656 - not ok

so far I have found this solution:

```
/^-?\d*[.,]?\d*$/.test(value)
```

but it doesn't cover these cases:

1. `.0565656`
2. `056565`
3. `0.0000005`

Comment: Try `^(?:\d+[.,]\d+|[1-9]\d*)$` See https://regex101.com/r/nhEBoM/1

Comment: Can you describe in words what is OK and what isn't OK? That's usually the first step to create a regex. E.g. "input has to start with a X followed by a one ore more Y".

Comment: If the `ok` should be matched, and the `not ok` including the last 3 examples should not be matched `^(?:[1-9]\d*|\d+(?:,\d+|\.[1-9]\d*))$` https://regex101.com/r/COr1ys/1

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution. you can check it out here - https://jsfiddle.net/r6yj4skd/15/. as you can see, I can't start with 0. plus I cant clear the input (there's always a digit left)

Answer (score 0):

Should work like this:

```
/^(0[.,]{1}|[1-9]{1})\d*[.,]?\d*$/.test(value);
```

For playing around, I strongly recommend Regex101. Here is your regex on Regex101 with the test cases https://regex101.com/r/Mmf671/2/

EDIT:
If you want to allow empty strings as well, then use this:

```
/(^$|^(0[.,]{1}|[1-9]{1})\d*[.,]?\d*$)/.test(value);
  ^^
// Note the marked difference in order to allow for empty strings
```

Comment: Thanks, almost exactly what i need, but still, not it) Here is the link - https://jsfiddle.net/6qwc9ey4/13/. I can't clear the input field

Comment: For this you can add the possibility for an empty string: `return /(^$|^(0[.,]{1}|[1-9]{1})\d*[.,]?\d*$)/.test(value);`

Comment: it works, but i can't start with 0 - https://jsfiddle.net/1ops7Lb8/3/

Comment: `{1}` has no real need. Whatever that matches would run the same without it.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `^-?(?!0\d)\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?$`

`(?!0\d)` is a negative lookahead that makes sure we haven't `0` followed by a digit at the beginning.

```js
var test = [
    '1255454',
    '1.54546',
    '1,0056',
    '0.6565',
    '0,0056',
    '-123',
    '-0.123',
    '-05',
    '056565',
    'ds5asd',
    '.0565656',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' : '+/^-?(?!0\d)\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?$/.test(a);
}));
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/5vB9zl/1)